# Creating a parallax vertical background moving down

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Using `as3`, i want to create a parallax vertical background moving down. here's what i tried.

```
addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );

    public function onEnterFrame( evt:Event ):void
    {
        plane.y = plane.y + 50;
        roadContainer.y = 190 - plane.y;

        if ( road.y + roadBreadth + roadContainer.y < 0 )
        {
            road.y = road.y + (2 * roadBreadth);
        }
        if ( road2.y + roadBreadth + roadContainer.y < 0 )
        {
            road2.y = road2.y + (2 * roadBreadth);
        }

    }
```

Any help to make this parallax vertical background moving down into parallax vertical backround moving up?

Comment: Does "parallax vertical background" actually mean `plane` or `road` or `roadContainer`? Which thing in your code do you want to move upwards? You want to try: _something_.y -= _number_ (use minus not plus for reverse movement)

Answer (score 0):

As in your post you can use [**Event.ENTER_FRAME**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html) event handler function to continuously increment the y property of your image movieclips. Also you can easily use the [**z-index property**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/all-index-Z.html) of objects to fake parallax. Take the effort to scroll one image and you can easily apply it to multiple images/movieclips.

**Example for a z property:**

You can set up movieclips of your scenes and then set up your movieclips for the various depths (closer, middle, far, further, etc....) and assign a depth to each movieclip with higher numbers for the further away slower moving parts. You can then just tween the scenes.

[Also there are plenty of help if you spend time googling](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-depth-to-your-game-with-parallax-scrolling--active-2134).

**Reference:**

1. [Z-Index](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/all-index-Z.html)
2. [Event.ENTER_FRAME](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html)